# Fitting a HTML table in a specific area

Tags: php, html, css

I'm building a HTML table that displays information from a MySQL database with functions that update or delete rows in the database.

Here's my code at the minute:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Program</th>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Start Date</th>
    <th>End Date</th>
    <th>Country</th>
</tr>

<?php

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM  student_management_module";

    $db->setQuery($query);
            $rows = $db->loadObjectList();

            foreach ($rows as &$row) {
                echo "<form action=index.php/component/studentmanagement/?task=update method=post>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=fname id=name_val value=" .$row->name. " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=email id=email_val value=" .$row->email. " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=prog id=prog_val value=" .$row->program. " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=class id=class_val value=" .$row->class. " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=sdate id=start_val value=" .$row->start_date. " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=edate id=end_val value=" .$row->end_date. " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=country id=country_val value=" .$row->country. " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" .$row->student_id. " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update". " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete value=delete". " </td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</form>";
            }

    ?>
```

Here's what the tables looks like currently:

[Picture of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OSo4.jpg)

But there are too many columns to fit it in the space I want.

How can I create a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom and making sure that update and delete buttons are separated from that scroll bar, so that the update and insert buttons always show on the right side.

I've tried the CSS overflow property, but it includes the insert and delete in the scrolling.

Any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, You forgot to close the `input` tag:

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=fname id=name_val value=" .$row->name. "> </td>";
//-----------------------------------------------------------Here------------^
```

**Secondly**, you forgot `''` in the tag:

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='fname' id='name_val' value='" .$row->name. "'> </td>";
```

**Thirdly**, if you want a scroll bar horizontal you should look a this:

```css
        html{
          max-width: 100%;
          overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        
        .headcol {
          position: absolute;
          width: 120px;
          left: 0;
          top: auto;
          border-top-width: 1px;
          /*only relevant for first row*/
          margin-top: -1px;
          /*compensate for top border*/
        }

        .div {
          width: 86%;
          overflow-x: scroll;
          margin-left: 5em;
          overflow-y: visible;
          padding: 0;
        }
```

```html
 <html>
        <div class="div">
        <table style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto">
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Program</th>
                  <th>Class</th>
                  <th>Student ID</th>
                  <th>Start Date</th>
                  <th>End Date</th>
                  <th>Country</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <form>
              <td class="headcol"><input type="submit" name="update" value="update"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"></td>
                
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->name. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->mail. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Program. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Class. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->StudentID. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->StartDate. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->EndDate. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Country. "></td>
                 </form>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <form>
              <td class="headcol"><input type="submit" name="update" value="update"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"></td>
                
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->name. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->mail. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Program. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Class. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->StudentID. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->StartDate. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->EndDate. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Country. "></td>
                 </form>
              </tr>
<tr>
              <form>
              <td class="headcol"><input type="submit" name="update" value="update"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"></td>
                
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->name. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->mail. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Program. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Class. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->StudentID. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->StartDate. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->EndDate. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Country. "></td>
                 </form>
              </tr>
<tr>
              <form>
              <td class="headcol"><input type="submit" name="update" value="update"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"></td>
                
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->name. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->mail. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Program. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Class. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->StudentID. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->StartDate. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->EndDate. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Country. "></td>
                 </form>
              </tr>
<tr>
              <form>
              <td class="headcol"><input type="submit" name="update" value="update"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"></td>
                
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->name. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->mail. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Program. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Class. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->StudentID. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->StartDate. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->EndDate. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Country. "></td>
                 </form>
              </tr>
<tr>
              <form>
              <td class="headcol"><input type="submit" name="update" value="update"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"></td>
                
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->name. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->mail. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Program. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Class. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->StudentID. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->StartDate. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->EndDate. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Country. "></td>
                 </form>
              </tr>
<tr>
              <form>
              <td class="headcol"><input type="submit" name="update" value="update"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"></td>
                
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->name. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->mail. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Program. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Class. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->StudentID. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->StartDate. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->EndDate. "></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="name_val" value=" .$row->Country. "></td>
                 </form>
              </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: the question is not about the scrollbar that the op sees showing up, but **how to keep the update and delete button always at sight** on the right even when you have to scroll to see the las column ...

Comment: looks better ;) , i belive he was trying to keep the button on the right ;)

Answer (score -1):

**Explain donwvotes ... do not tell me it is about pHp before a second look at this very answer (maybe read the question again)  and after you understood what this very answer is about .... `HTML`&`CSS`tags only**

---

your code is full of mistake (closing tag , unvalid structure .. ) . This official online tool can help you findout your mistakes : https://validator.w3.org/

- You can use the form to wrap the entire table, it will provide a valid HTML structure and will create your scrollbar.
- update and delete button can be wrap in a single cell , so you have to mind about a single cell.

CSS propose nowdays `position:sticky` (and javascript polyfills for older browsers )
take a look at https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/ and https://css-tricks.com/stickybits-alternative-position-sticky-polyfills/

> Sticky positioning is a hybrid of relative and fixed positioning. The element is treated as relative positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed positioned.

example of what you could do :

```css
form {
  max-width:100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

form table tr td:last-child {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<form><!-- use the form as the wrapper to scroll -->
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Program</th>
      <th>Class</th>
      <th>Student ID</th>
      <th>Start Date</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th colspan=5></th><!-- html update numbers of column must be equal on each rows -->
    </tr>
    <!-- below your rendered HTML cleaned up from the php useless in snippet to demonstrate the CSS DEMO about sticky -->
    <tr>
      <td><input type=text name=fname id=name_val value="name"><!-- html update closing tag on input --></td>
      <td><input type=text name=email id=email_val value="email. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=prog  id=prog_val value="program. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=class id=class_val value=">class. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=sdate id=start_val value="start_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=edate id=end_val value="end_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=hidden name=hidden value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=submit name=update value="update"> <input type=submit name=delete value="delete"><!-- html update both button in a single cell --> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type=text name=fname id=name_val value="name"><!-- html update closing tag on input --></td>
      <td><input type=text name=email id=email_val value="email. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=prog  id=prog_val value="program. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=class id=class_val value=">class. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=sdate id=start_val value="start_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=edate id=end_val value="end_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=hidden name=hidden value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=submit name=update value="update"> <input type=submit name=delete value="delete"><!-- html update both button in a single cell --> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type=text name=fname id=name_val value="name"><!-- html update closing tag on input --></td>
      <td><input type=text name=email id=email_val value="email. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=prog  id=prog_val value="program. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=class id=class_val value=">class. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=sdate id=start_val value="start_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=edate id=end_val value="end_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=hidden name=hidden value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=submit name=update value="update"> <input type=submit name=delete value="delete"><!-- html update both button in a single cell --> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type=text name=fname id=name_val value="name"><!-- html update closing tag on input --></td>
      <td><input type=text name=email id=email_val value="email. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=prog  id=prog_val value="program. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=class id=class_val value=">class. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=sdate id=start_val value="start_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=edate id=end_val value="end_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=hidden name=hidden value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=submit name=update value="update"> <input type=submit name=delete value="delete"><!-- html update both button in a single cell --> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type=text name=fname id=name_val value="name"><!-- html update closing tag on input --></td>
      <td><input type=text name=email id=email_val value="email. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=prog  id=prog_val value="program. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=class id=class_val value=">class. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=sdate id=start_val value="start_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=edate id=end_val value="end_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=hidden name=hidden value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=submit name=update value="update"> <input type=submit name=delete value="delete"><!-- html update both button in a single cell --> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

idem with the polyfill in action where browser still need javascript

```js
// https://dollarshaveclub.github.io/stickybits/
(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
  (global.stickybits = factory());
}(this, (function () { 'use strict';

var browserPrefix = ['', '-o-', '-webkit-', '-moz-', '-ms-'];
var stickyBitClass = 'js-is-sticky';
var stickyBitIsStuckClass = 'js-is-stuck';

function Stickybit(target, o) {
  this.el = target;
  this.scrollTarget = o && o.scrollTarget || window;
  this.stickyBitStickyOffset = o && o.stickyBitStickyOffset || 0;
  this.verticalPosition = o && o.verticalPosition || 'top';
  this.useStickyClasses = o && o.useStickyClasses || false;
  this.elStyle = this.el.style;
  this.positionStickyVal = 'fixed';
}

Stickybit.prototype.setStickyPosition = function setStickyPosition() {
  var elStyle = this.elStyle;
  var verticalPosition = this.verticalPosition;
  for (var i = 0; i < browserPrefix.length; i += 1) {
    elStyle.position = browserPrefix[i] + 'sticky';
  }
  if (elStyle.position !== '') {
    this.positionStickyVal = elStyle.position;
    if (verticalPosition === 'top') {
      elStyle[verticalPosition] = this.stickyBitStickyOffset + 'px';
    }
  }
};

Stickybit.prototype.manageStickiness = function manageStickiness() {
  var el = this.el;
  var scrollTarget = this.scrollTarget;
  var positionStickyVal = this.positionStickyVal;
  var verticalPosition = this.verticalPosition;
  var stickyBitStickyOffset = this.stickyBitStickyOffset;
  var elStyle = this.elStyle;
  var elClasses = el.classList;
  var elParent = el.parentNode;
  var stickyBitStart = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var stickyBitStop = stickyBitStart + elParent.offsetHeight - (el.offsetHeight - stickyBitStickyOffset);
  elParent.classList.add('js-stickybit-parent');
  function stickiness() {
    var scroll = scrollTarget.scrollY;
    if (scroll < stickyBitStart) {
      if (elClasses.contains(stickyBitClass)) {
        elClasses.remove(stickyBitClass);
        if (positionStickyVal === 'fixed') elStyle.position = '';
      }
    } else if (scroll > stickyBitStart && scroll < stickyBitStop) {
      if (!elClasses.contains(stickyBitClass)) elClasses.add(stickyBitClass);
      if (elClasses.contains(stickyBitIsStuckClass)) {
        elClasses.remove(stickyBitIsStuckClass);
        elStyle.bottom = '';
      }
      elStyle.position = positionStickyVal;
      elStyle[verticalPosition] = stickyBitStickyOffset + 'px';
    } else if (scroll > stickyBitStop && !elClasses.contains(stickyBitIsStuckClass)) {
      elClasses.remove(stickyBitClass);
      elClasses.add(stickyBitIsStuckClass);
      if (positionStickyVal !== 'fixed') return;
      elStyle.top = '';
      elStyle.bottom = '0';
      elStyle.position = 'absolute';
    }
  }
  var invoked = void 0;
  function checkStickiness() {
    if (invoked) return;
    invoked = true;
    stickiness();
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      invoked = false;
    }, 0);
  }
  scrollTarget.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    return scrollTarget.requestAnimationFrame(checkStickiness);
  });
};

function stickybits(target, o) {
  var els = typeof target === 'string' ? document.querySelectorAll(target) : target;
  if (!('length' in els)) els = [els];
  var stickyBit = void 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i += 1) {
    var el = els[i];
    stickyBit = new Stickybit(el, o);
    stickyBit.setStickyPosition();
    if (stickyBit.positionStickyVal === 'fixed' || stickyBit.useStickyClasses === true) {
      stickyBit.manageStickiness();
    }
  }
}

return stickybits;

})));

var $fixedEl = $('#fixed-child');
var $fixedParent = $('#fixed-parent');
var stickyCoords = {};
function getStickyCoords() {
  stickyCoords.start = $fixedParent.offset().top;
  var parentHeight = $fixedParent.outerHeight();
  var fixedElHeight = $fixedEl.outerHeight();
  var distance = parentHeight - fixedElHeight;
  stickyCoords.stop =  stickyCoords.start + distance;
  return stickyCoords; 
};
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scroll = window.scrollY;
  getStickyCoords();
  if (scroll < stickyCoords.start) {
    $fixedEl.removeClass('js-is-fixed');
    return;
  } else if (
    (scroll > stickyCoords.start) && 
    (scroll < stickyCoords.stop)
  ) {
   $fixedEl.addClass('js-is-fixed');
   $fixedEl.removeClass('js-is-fixed-stuck');
    return;
  } else {
   $fixedEl.addClass('js-is-fixed-stuck');
   $fixedEl.removeClass('js-is-fixed');
  }
});

stickybits('#sticky-child');
```

```css
form {
  max-width:100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

form table tr td:last-child {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form><!-- use the form as the wrapper to scroll -->
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Program</th>
      <th>Class</th>
      <th>Student ID</th>
      <th>Start Date</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th colspan=5></th><!-- html update numbers of column must be equal on each rows -->
    </tr>
    <!-- below your rendered HTML cleaned up from the php useless in snippet to demonstrate the CSS DEMO about sticky -->
    <tr>
      <td><input type=text name=fname id=name_val value="name"><!-- html update closing tag on input --></td>
      <td><input type=text name=email id=email_val value="email. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=prog  id=prog_val value="program. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=class id=class_val value=">class. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=sdate id=start_val value="start_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=edate id=end_val value="end_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=hidden name=hidden value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=submit name=update value="update"> <input type=submit name=delete value="delete"><!-- html update both button in a single cell --> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type=text name=fname id=name_val value="name"><!-- html update closing tag on input --></td>
      <td><input type=text name=email id=email_val value="email. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=prog  id=prog_val value="program. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=class id=class_val value=">class. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=sdate id=start_val value="start_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=edate id=end_val value="end_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=hidden name=hidden value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=submit name=update value="update"> <input type=submit name=delete value="delete"><!-- html update both button in a single cell --> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type=text name=fname id=name_val value="name"><!-- html update closing tag on input --></td>
      <td><input type=text name=email id=email_val value="email. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=prog  id=prog_val value="program. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=class id=class_val value=">class. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=sdate id=start_val value="start_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=edate id=end_val value="end_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=hidden name=hidden value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=submit name=update value="update"> <input type=submit name=delete value="delete"><!-- html update both button in a single cell --> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type=text name=fname id=name_val value="name"><!-- html update closing tag on input --></td>
      <td><input type=text name=email id=email_val value="email. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=prog  id=prog_val value="program. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=class id=class_val value=">class. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=sdate id=start_val value="start_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=edate id=end_val value="end_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=hidden name=hidden value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=submit name=update value="update"> <input type=submit name=delete value="delete"><!-- html update both button in a single cell --> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type=text name=fname id=name_val value="name"><!-- html update closing tag on input --></td>
      <td><input type=text name=email id=email_val value="email. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=prog  id=prog_val value="program. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=class id=class_val value=">class. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=sdate id=start_val value="start_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=edate id=end_val value="end_date. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=text name=stdid id=stdid_val value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=hidden name=hidden value="student_id. "></td>
      <td><input type=submit name=update value="update"> <input type=submit name=delete value="delete"><!-- html update both button in a single cell --> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Your code is full of mistakes as well.  Always use `htmlspecialchars()` or equivalent when inserting arbitrary data into HTML.  Otherwise, you risk creating invalid HTML and security issues.

Comment: @brad ?? this is plain HTML code , no php .... feel free to give 101 lessons on using forms, building table and writing Php codes ....

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm very new to web developing (this being my first project), so I was wondering if you could point out the invalid structures and other mistakes in my code.

Comment: @Kilter Within your PHP script you forgot to close the input tag. A form cannot be a direct child of `tr`. `tr`can only have td or th elements for childs. But your form can hold the entire table where input are, this will work.  There is an official online tool that will help you find out mistakes r missprints in your HTML code rendered by your server : https://validator.w3.org/ . besides, the web is full of 101 tutorials on how to build an HTML table ,You will also find many tutorials about building forms , using them and how to style them.

Comment: @Kilter thanks for your feedback, but did the answer provided you some clues and does it behave as expected ... just to know that i understood your question. downvotes seems to tell this answers doesn't answer the question ....?

Comment: @G-Cyr Thanks so much for the advice! The answer was exactly what I was looking for, so I'm not sure why there are downvotes.